# Facebook Login and get post by command line

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the each user's FB posts by commandline.

like

whitebear@bear.com

blackbear@bear.com

yellowbear@bear.com

These are my code.

```
    $secret = 'xxxxx';
    $key = 'xxxx';
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
    . $key . "&client_secret=" . $secret . "&grant_type=client_credentials";
    print $url. "\n";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url),true);
    var_dump($json['access_token']); // success

    $url2 =  "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=posts&access_token=" .$json['access_token'];

    $json2 = json_decode(file_get_contents($url2),true);
    var_dump($json2); //
```

`Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=posts&access_token=4887415xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`

I succeed to get the `access_token`, however I think it is facebook app's accesstoken?? not user's??

I think I should indicate the who is the user before loading `me?` api.

However how should I do?

I let every user login on web application AOuth and stored each `users` `facebook_access_token` in DataBase (but it valid a few hours????)

Comment: You have the user login using Facebook login and them for permission to access their posts. Then you get an access token you can use to access them

Answer (score 1):

- If you need to store a User Token, you should use an **Extended User Token**
- You cannot get a User Token programmatically, only on user interaction with a proper login process
- You can debug Tokens to see if it is an App or User Token in the [Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/)

More Information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

`grant_type=client_credentials` generates [an app token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens).

> App access tokens are used to make requests to Facebook APIs on behalf of an app rather than a user. This can be used to modify the parameters of your app, create and manage test users, or read your apps's insights.
>
> Some user data that would normally be visible to an app making a request with a user access token isn't always visible with an app access token. If you're reading user data and using it in your app, you should use a user access token instead of an app access token.

You can not use app tokens to access `me` or fetch most data about individual users.

Comment: I have each user's access token, now I wonder how to use each user's access token to (login?) and get `/me?`

Comment: You don't log in. You just pass the right access token. `/me` means "the owner of the current token".